# Probability proof of indicator random variable$I_AI_B = I_{A \cap B}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing

If I have events $A$ and $B$ over some probability space $(\Omega, Pr)$

And $I$ is the indicator random variable such that $I_A$ is $1$ if $A$ occurs and $0$ if $A$ does not occur

How can I prove that

$I_AI_B = I_{A \cap B}$

I know that $I_AI_B(\omega) = I_A(\omega) \cdot I_B(\omega)$. What do i do from here?

Comment: You literally just go through all cases (e.g. $x \in A \cap B$, $x \in A \setminus (A \cap B)$) - draw a Venn diagram for the sets $A$ and $B$ if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For any event $E$, the indicator $\mathbf I_E$ has value $1$ when the event occurs, else $0$ when it does not.

Thus $\mathbf I_{A}\,\mathbf I_{B}$ will have value $1$ when both events $A$ and $B$ occur, else $0$ when one does not.

Also $\mathbf I_{A\cap B}$ will have value $1$ when both events $A$ and $B$ occur, else $0$ when one does not.

$\therefore\quad\mathbf I_{A\cap B}=\mathbf I_A\,\mathbf I_B$

That is all.

Comment: Yes. Event $A\cap B$ occurs exactly when both events $A$ and $B$ do; since all outcomes in $A\cap B$ are outcomes in both $A$ and $B$, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Gamma = \{ w \in \Omega : w \in A\}$ and $\Xi = \{ w \in \Omega : w \in B\}$ and notice that $\Gamma \cap \Xi = \{ w \in \Omega : w \in A \cap B\}$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
I_A I_B (w) & =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } I_A(w) = I_B(w) =1\\
0, & \text{ if } I_A(w) = 0 \text{ or } I_B(w) =0
\end{cases}
=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } w \in \Gamma \text{ and } w \in \Xi\\
0, & \text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases}
\\
& =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } w \in \Gamma \cap \Xi\\
0, & \text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases}
=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } I_{A \cap B}(w) = 1\\
0, & \text{ if } I_{A \cap B}(w) = 0 
\end{cases}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

In conclusion,
$$I_AI_B = I_{A \cap B}.$$